# IO bottleneck queries DMVs in sql server

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

I am looking for troubleshooting IO bottleneck in my system. I have two SQL Servers running one with SQL Server 2012 and other one is on SQL Server 2016 both are in Standard Edition.

I am facing lots of performance issues and thru DMV's i found most of these are due to IOPS and IO related bottlenecks, some queries i used are below:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_os_wait_stats
WHERE wait_type LIKE 'PAGEIOLATCH%'
ORDER BY wait_type ASC
```

Pending I/O requests can be found by querying the following DMVs and can be used to identify which disk is responsible for the bottleneck.

```
SELECT
    database_id,
    file_id,
    io_stall,
    io_pending_ms_ticks,
    scheduler_address
FROM    sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats(NULL, NULL) iovfs,
        sys.dm_io_pending_io_requests AS iopior
WHERE iovfs.file_handle = iopior.io_handle
```

But still I am not able to get consolidated list of IO issues, Can you help me on the list of all IO issues and corresponding DMV's queries to troubleshoot?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: have you ran Brent Ozar's sp_Blitz queries? specifically, it looks like sp_BlitzFirst might get you basically what you're looking for, https://www.brentozar.com/askbrent/ . the queries you're looking for are complicated, to say the least.

Comment: but if you really want something this specific, it looks like this page has a query for you, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dpless/2010/12/01/leveraging-sys-dm_io_virtual_file_stats/ .

Comment: Nice article i will use that to continue my further analysis

Comment: As i mentioned in the query i posted i am able to see reads, writes, stalls etc (provided by sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats)., but still not able to map myself with IO bottleneck, With these Info how can I find there is a bottleneck in IO? is my question

Comment: I doubt that you can, without any context to what the numbers should be. most troubleshooting guides start by saying that you should compare your numbers with a baseline. I'm assuming that you do not have one. what the numbers should be for your system will be entirely different than what they should be for someone else's system. I would greatly suggest that you step back a bit and run all of the sp_blitz queries, and start with things that they identify as likely problems.

Comment: I also found this article, but it goes beyond the DMV's, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqljourney/2013/06/03/how-to-troubleshooting-sql-server-io-bottlenecks/ .

Comment: I totally agree that it is a step by step process which i started with.. I found that server got good max memory setup and it is not heavy on memory pressure and processor as well, But while monitoring i found slowness due to disk IO only.. But I am looking for some DMV's or queries which I can finalize that it is due to IO bottleneck only...